# How to select same value fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the follwoing fields name, address, city, zip, etc.

How do you select the city column with same value?

Comment: Can you add some details on what you want?

Comment: What does it mean of "select the city column with same value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want.

If you want a list of the cities that appear more than once you can use:

```
select city, count(city) Total
from yourtable
group by city
having count(city) > 1
```

If you want to return data based on the city name, you will use:

```
select *
from yourtable 
where city = 'yourCity'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all entries in New York assuming your table name is called locations

```
SELECT name, address, zip, city FROM locations WHERE city LIKE "New York"
```

If you want all the entries to be ordered by city so that they are clustered together:

```
SELECT name, address, zip, city FROM locations ORDER BY city DESC
```

If you want to collect a list of names from each city:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM locations GROUP BY city;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select city from table_name group by city having count(city) > 1;
```